# Why 'mapred-site.xml' is not included in the latest Hadoop 2.2.0?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Latest build of Hadoop provides `mapred-site.xml.template`
 Do we need to create a new `mapred-site.xml` file using this? 
 Any link on documentation or explanation related to Hadoop 2.2.0 will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I *believe* it's still required. For our basic Hadoop 2.2.0 2-node cluster setup that we have working I did the following from the setup documentation.

"

From the base of the Hadoop installation, edit the etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml file. A new 
configuration option for Hadoop 2 is the capability to specify a framework name for 
MapReduce, setting the mapreduce.framework.name property. In this install we will use the 
value of "yarn" to tell MapReduce that it will run as a YARN application.
First, copy the template file to the mapred-site.xml.

> cp mapred-site.xml.template mapred-site.xml

Next, copy the following into Hadoop etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml file and remove the original empty   tags.

```
 <configuration> 
 <property>   
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>  
 <value>yarn</value>  
 </property>   
 </configuration>
```

"

Wrt documentation, I found [this](http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2013/06/Apache.Hadoop.YARN_.Sample.pdf) the most useful. Also, etc/hosts configs for cluster setup and other cluster related configs were a bit hard to figure out.